# MySQL High Insertion Rate for Bulk Inserts (InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, innodb, bulkinsert

I recently conducted a mysqlslap stress test to determine which type of insert is best from a performance standpoint. The files containing the queries were stored on a linux system and read from it. I hope someone could through some insight on this. Following are the benchmark obtained through mysqlslap test:

```
Time taken for Individual/Separate Insert: 5.24 seconds
Time taken for Batch Insert: 2.77 seconds
Time taken for Bulk Insert: 0.52 seconds

MySQL Version: 5.6.14 (InnoDB)
Total Records inserted on empty table: 5000
The records put together has size < 10kb
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed is disabled
Query cache turned off
```

Does it have to do anything with parsing, `Created_tmp_tables` or `Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed` or any `global variables`?

Comment: refer this link: http://www.dslreports.com/shownews/Mysql-and-a-billion-rows-using-innodb-87890

Comment: The link does not say why bulk inserts are faster.